On the Noether normalization of coordinate ring of an affine variety ( Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms ).

Theorem 6 ( Noether Normalization, Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms, p.284 ). Let $k$ be an infinite field and suppose that we are given a finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$. Then :

(i) There are algebraically independent elements $u_1 , \dots, u_m \in A$ such that $A$ is finite over $k[u_1, \dots, u_m]$.
(ii) If $A$ is generated by $s_1 , \dots, s_l$ as a $k$-algebra, then $m\le l$ and $u_1, \dots, u_m$ can be chosen to be $k$-linear combinations of $s_1, \dots, s_l$.


Assume that $k$ is an algebraically closed field, hence infinite. The coordinate ring $k[V] \cong k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I(V)$ of an affine variety $V\subseteq k^n$ has a Noether normalization $k[u_1, \dots, u_m] \subseteq k[V]$ such that the $u_i$ are algebraically independent over $k$ and $k[V]$ is finite over $k[u_1, \dots , u_m]$. Note that each $u_i$ can be choosen as $k$-linear combinations of the coordinate functions $\phi_i = [x_i] \in k[V]$, since $\phi_i$'s are algebra generators of $k[V]$ over $k$. Consider the corresponding projection map $\pi : V \to k^m$ from the inclusion $k[u_1, \dots, u_m] \subseteq k[V]$. We want to show that $m$ is the dimension of $V$ ( C.f. Ideals, Varieties, and algorithms, Chapter 9, section 5, Theorem 6 ), in particular, $m \ge \dim V$.
My question is, by a suitable change of coordinates in $k^n$, why can we assume that $u_i = [x_i]$ for $i=1, \dots,m $ ? It is about linear algebra problem ?
